# Reorganizar índices autoincrementables en MYSQL.

Tags: mysql, vb.net

es una conexión MYSQL y VB.NET. El botón eliminar contiene el DELETE FROM Tabla WHERE N = Número; En conclusión, quedan índices sin uso. ¿cómo haría para que la posición 2 pase a ser 1, la 3 a 2 y la 5 a 3? Gracias de antemano, saludos y bendiciones.

[image]

Comment: Los ID son datos opacos, no deberias mostrarlos ni cambiarlos, ademas son valores que pueden cambiar de una instalacion a otra instalacion. Hacer esto puede romper la integridad de la base o si la corriges tendra un costo alto.

Comment: Entonces, ¿no debería usar índice en los registros si estos pueden ser eliminados?

Comment: Si, usa IDs: son muy utiles para relacionar registros (un cliente y un pago por ejemplo) pero no deberia importe el valor de ese campo, lo importante es que el pago tenga el ID de cliente correcto. No lo confundas con el codigo del cliente (el que se usa para buscar el producto que es muy comun en muchos sistemas). El ID es una forma de relacionar los registros que solo existe para el programa (para el programador). Al usuario no le sirve de nada saber el ID. Por eso es mejor ni siquiera mostrarlo para no crear confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es complicado hacer esta clase de actualizaciones. Citando ["Los diez mandamientos de Access"](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm) (aplicables en algunos casos a cualquier RDBMS):

> 7. Thou shalt not use Autonumber if the field is meant to have meaning for thy users.
>      (*No usareis 'Autonumérico` si el campo debe tener significado para vuestros usuarios*)

El campo `N`, según lo que veo, cumple con funciones de índice, por lo que puede ser usado para ordenar; pero si deseas un valor incremental para mostrarlo, lo mejor es generarlo al vuelo al momento de ejecutar la consulta:

```
select @n := @n + 1 as N2
     , Tabla.*
from (select @n := 0) as init
   , Tabla
-- where Tabla.N IN (...)
order by Tabla.N;
```

Al momento de seleccionar o borrar registros, debes filtrar por el valor guardado en la tabla. Pero el número de fila lo puedes generar al momento de ejecutar tu consulta.

---

**Más opciones**

Si deseas ir mostrando las filas en bloques, podrías escribir un procedimiento almacenado que te devuelva las filas, y vaya numerando los registros iniciando en el número de fila que vas a mostrar:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure miProc(nReg int unsigned, regIni int unsigned)
-- nReg:   Número de registros a mostrar
-- regIni: Primer registro a mostrar
begin
  select @n := @n+1 as N2
       , Tabla.*
  from (select @n := regIni) as init
     , Tabla
  order by Tabla.N
  limit regIni, nReg;
end $$
delimiter ;
```